# When should I use SQL standard types over generic types in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

Consider an instance of `datetime.datetime` from the Python standard library. We can either store such instance as the generic type `sqlalchemy.types.DateTime` or the SQL standard type `sqlalchemy.types.DATETIME`.

The SQL standard type has the limitation that it will only work on those backends that explicitly support them by name as mentioned [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sql-standard-and-multiple-vendor-types) . The generic type has no such limitation.

Is there ever a case that using the SQL standard type is preferred over generic type?

Comment: *"Is there ever a case that using the SQL standard type is preferred over generic type?"* – One example is in the SQLAlchemy documentation you cited [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY) regarding the `ARRAY` type.